# Error : no such partition

Tags: partitioning

I took an empty partition on my hard disk, and put it into a gtp??? file and made it primary. When I restarted my laptop I got the following error message:

```
no such partition  
grub rescue>
```

Now I'm stuck. I tried to recover with a Windows 7 DVD, but it says it's not compatible with Windows. I bought the laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 on it, and now I want to install Windows 7, but I can't install it and I can't remove Ubuntu. Now I'm stuck, and do not know what else I can do. Please someone help.

Comment: It's rather difficult to read your question without meaningful punctuation and text structure.

Comment: @vincent Are you sure you didn't mean **GPT** file instead of **gtp**? GPT, or GUID Partition Table, is the disk partitioning format commonly used by EFI-compliant firmware.

Comment: @ karel i'm not really good with computers so it might be an GPT file asswel because i wanted to install windows on it

Answer (score 0):

Please check and try to correct the device boot order in your BIOS. Maybe the new drive snuck in front of your system drive.